# How can I verify if an URL (https) exists in C language?

Tags: c

I don't know if exists function that allows me to know if an URL exists.
I hope it is possible this in C language.

Comment: Technically speaking, any URL "exists" as long as you write it somewhere. I suspect you actually need to check whether requesting it returns a 200 HTTP code, am I right ?

Comment: what do you mean, exists? Find a url in a string? or figure out if the url is actually valid and doesn't return a 404? The only way to check if it represents a valid resource is to actually hit the url (e.g. do an http request) and check for errors.

Comment: I meant if a website exists.
Yes, that doesn't return 404 or other errors.

Comment: You could make use of libcurl. See the example code for [curl_easy_perform](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/), here's a small C program that uses the function `check_url` to test a URL. The function returns `1` if the request succeeded and `0` otherwise.

Invoke like:

`./a.out http://example.com`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

int check_url(char *url)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode response;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

        /* don't write output to stdout */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

        /* Perform the request */
        response = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return (response == CURLE_OK) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result = check_url(argv[1]);

    if (result)
        printf("Success!\n");
    else
        printf("Failed...\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution that assumes `wget` is properly installed and in `$PATH`, and that your system is uncompromised. Read more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/) about why using `std::system` is considered harmful and shouldn't be used in production code.

In c++:

```
int webCheck(const std::string &url)
{
    return (std::system(("wget --spider -q " + url).c_str()));
}
```

So I guess that in C:

```
int webCheck(const char url[])
{
    return (system(strcat("wget --spider -q ", url)));
}
```

It returns 0 if all went well, so you could do this:

```
if(!webCheck("http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/"))
{
    printf("OK");
}
```

Here are the values that it could return:

```
> 0.   No problems occurred.
> 1.   Generic error code.
> 2.   Parse error---for instance, when parsing command-line options, the .wgetrc or .netrc...
> 3.   File I/O error. 
> 4.   Network failure. 
> 5.   SSL verification failure. 
> 6.   Username/password authentication failure. 
> 7. Protocol errors.
>8   Server issued an error response.
> 
> With the exceptions of 0 and 1, the lower-numbered exit codes take
> precedence over higher-numbered ones, when multiple types of errors
> are encountered.
```

Source: [wget man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)